# How do I prove this using van-Kampen theorem informally ? (2)

Tags: algebraic-topology

The second( and the last) problem is this

[image]

Could someone please help me how to calculate $\pi_1(X)$?

Comment: @DanielRust I want to believe it..

Comment: Is that a link, @Rubertos?

Comment: @BalarkaSen No, I can just upload a picture for you. It's just one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An informal calculation might go as follows. First, let's "push" one of the circles to infinity so that we're instead removing a copy of $S^1$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ which 'goes through' the circle and goes off towards infinity along the $z$-coordinate. You should hopefully be able to see that this space is a kind of 'maximally fattened up torus' in $3$-space. That is, if we just start expanding the torus as much as we can in all direction in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the only bits which we would not be able to 'fill in' by this fattening process would be a circle inside the complement of the torus, and a line going through the 'hole' in our torus. So our space should have the same fundamental group as the torus, namely $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

To prove this formally, one would need to use Van-Kampen's theorem, to show that $\pi_1(S^3\setminus L)\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus L)$ where we view $S^3$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This makes the 'pushing the circle to infinity' part of the above actually work. The 'fattening up' process is really just saying that this new space deformaiton retracts onto a torus.

Comment: (Sorry I have to leave so won't be able to answer any questions about this, admittedly hard to visualise, answer - hopefully someone else can help if it's needed)

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to understand the intuition of a relation at a crossing, as follows:

[image: crossing]

I have demonstrated this to children with a copper tubing pentoil and a nice length of rope. For the connection with the van Kampen theorem, see my book [Topology and Groupoids](http://grooupoids.co.uk/topgpds.html), p. 349.